# Using CastCompanionLibrary adds multiple processes to app

Tags: android, chromecast

I've added ChromeCast support to my app using the CastCompanionLibrary.

When I go into the application manager on my device, go to running apps and look at my app, it's now running multiple additional processes, including:

- YouTube

(Service YouTube TV Service in use

- Allcast

(Service Amazon Fire TV in use)

- Allcast

(Service Chromecast in use)

I'm not sure if this is a problem or not, but it leads to users believing and complaining that the app is using more resources than it needs to (whether significant or not).

I'd like to know if it's supposed to be displaying additional processes, particularly ones not used by the app and whether that indicates the app is consuming more resources than it should.

[image: Multiple running processes]

Comment: Are you claiming that your app, which apparently uses CCL, spawns processes related to YouTube and AllCast and you believe it is because your app is using CCL?  Rest assured, CCL has nothing to do with any of those apps/processes.

Comment: My guess is that those processes are there (except perhaps YouTube) because you are using `MediaRouter`, perhaps in conjunction with `MediaRouteActionProvider`, whether directly or through CCL. In order to determine the available media routes, the registered `MediaRouteProvider`s need to be invoked. Users, like you, who have third-party providers (e.g., AllCast) installed, will see more processes.

Comment: I figured it must have something to do with all these apps having something in common - to do with ChromeCast support. Should I care about this at all?

Answer (score -1):

In CastCompanionLibrary project, open BaseCastManager.java and comment CATEGORY_LIVE_AUDIO and CATEGORY_LIVE_VIDEO

`mMediaRouteSelector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder().addControlCategory(CastMediaControlIntent.categoryForCast(mApplicationId))
//              .addControlCategory(MediaControlIntent.CATEGORY_LIVE_AUDIO)
//                  .addControlCategory(MediaControlIntent.CATEGORY_LIVE_VIDEO)
                    .addControlCategory(MediaControlIntent.CATEGORY_REMOTE_PLAYBACK)
                    .build();`

Comment: I don't know where you get your CastCompanionLibrary from but there is no CATEGORY_LIVE_AUDIO or VIDEO there in the official one.

Comment: i'm using v1.8 of the library, and it is here: https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android/blob/master/src/com/google/sample/castcompanionlibrary/cast/BaseCastManager.java#L207

Comment: What I see there is:
 mMediaRouteSelector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder().addControlCategory(
                CastMediaControlIntent.categoryForCast(mApplicationId)).build();
not what you had mentioned; where do you see CATEGORY_LIVE_AUDIO??

Comment: There is no such code in CCL, and your link does not prove otherwise.